# Why does this UIView move?

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout

Initial constraint...

```
let conBottom = imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: imageView.frame.height)
```

Then...

```
UIView.animate(
      withDuration: 0.67,
      delay: 2.0,
      animations: {
        conBottom.constant = imageView.frame.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      },
      completion: nil
    )
```

The contraint's constant doesn't change, and yet the animation results in the view disappearing off the end of the screen.

If I comment out the setting of the constant in the animation block, then the view doesn't move.

Why does the view move?

Comment: Print the original value and the value after change. Any warnings in the console?

Comment: What's the point of setting it in the animation block to the exact same value that it already had before the animation block? (And as a general rule, you should set autolayout constraints' constants *before* you invoke `animate()`, and have `animate()` just update the layout.)

Comment: @NRitH To weed out my lack of understand.

Comment: @NRitH I don't agree with your general rule, especially if there is 2 sec delay.

Comment: @Sulthan, you're right; I didn't notice the delay. If there's any delay, then the  layout will have already refreshed before your animation begins.

Answer (score 0):

It's because another constraint changes the height of the view before the animation block is run.